# Haskell function to return all powers of a number until a given maximum

Tags: function, haskell

I'm making a function that returns all the powers of n that are less than or equal to max. For example: `powers 2 5` --> [1,2,4].

```
myPowers n = n : map (* n) (myPowers n) 

powers :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
powers n max = takeWhile (< max) (myPowers n)
```

At the moment `powers` is returning too few numbers. For example: `powers 2 6` should return 3 numbers, but is returning 2 numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `myPowers` function starts with `n`, and not with `1`. For example:

```
Prelude> take 10 $ myPowers 2
[2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024]
```

We can fix this with:

```
myPowers n = 1 : map (* n) (myPowers n)
```

Note that you can make this computationally more efficient with [**`iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate), so you can define it as:

```
myPowers n = iterate (n*) 1
```

You should check the bound with `<=` if you want allow powers that are *equal* to the bounds:

```
powers n max = takeWhile (<= max) (myPowers n)
```

We then obtain sample output like:

```
Prelude> powers 2 5
[1,2,4]
Prelude> powers 2 6
[1,2,4]
Prelude> powers 2 10
[1,2,4,8]
Prelude> powers 3 10
[1,3,9]
Prelude> powers 3 30
[1,3,9,27]
Prelude> powers 5 30
[1,5,25]
```

Comment: I still have the same problem, and I think it's because of takeWhile (< max) If the power = max, then it will not be included. For example: powers 5 5. How could I fix this?

Comment: @Aelin: by changing it to `<=`. This was not completely clear from the problem description.

Comment: I actually tried to change it to `<=` earlier, before fixing the 1 at the start. It works now, thanks. :)